# how can i call the helper function from a catch block in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a vanilla javascript code that does some manipulation inside a function. If it errors out I want to retry it 2 times from the catch block

pseudocode below

```
main fn() {
  try {
    x = 0;

    //call a function here ;
    call function1();

  } catch (e) {
    if (x <= 2)
      call function1();
  }

  function1() {
    try {
      do some action here
    } catch (er) {
      throw err
    }
  }
```

Comment: Declaring functions inside blocks like that is kind-of a bad idea, as you've discovered. If the function is instead declared outside the `try {}` block, it's available to everything.

Comment: yes i tried that too the ,I separated out the helper function outside the try .then do ineed to keep a try catch inside the outside function  ? I am not able to connect that idea

Comment: If it is *inside* the outer `fn()` function, but *outside* the `try {} catch {}`, then it can be called from within the `try {}` and also within the `catch {}`.

Comment: @ays1: If you tried that, what problem did you encounter?  Instead of theorizing, please update the question to a [mcve] which demonstrates the specific problem.

Comment: specific issue is that if the function1 is called from catch block and if errors out how can it be handled to call one more time ?

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you used JavaScript instead of Psuedo-code and you used *logical indentation*. Tools like https://beautifier.io/ exist.

Comment: @ays1: You can put another nested `try` inside of the catch block. If you need more advanced retries, there are error-handling frameworks like [this one](https://github.com/mauricedb/polly-js).

Comment: What's the point of a `catch` block that simply does `throw err`?

Comment: @barmar can you please explain how we can achieve this if i dont provide the throw error inside the helper function ?The  logic should flow to the main function's catch block

Comment: @ays1: Why are you re-invoking the function on an exception anyway?  Perhaps you want to re-structure this to call the function in a loop until an exception isn't thrown?

Comment: Just get rid of the `try/catch` in `function1`. Any errors that occur will be thrown to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the actual underlying goal here is to re-try the function over and over until it *doesn't* throw an exception.  Considering that in a general context, repeatedly performing any operation sounds like the job of a loop.  For example:

```
while (true) {
  try {
    function1();
    break;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    continue;
  }
}
```

So as soon as `function1()` successfully executes without error (which ideally would even be on the first try), the loop exits.  But any time it throws an error, that error gets logged to the console and the loop repeats.  (The `continue;` is even superfluous here, but added to explicitly clarify the intent.)

---

Or, if the use of that `x` value is meant to illustrate a *re-try limit* (which is probably a good idea), that can be accomplished with a simple `for` loop:

```
for (let x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  try {
    function1();
    break;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    continue;
  }
}
```

You might even add some case to check if the function *never* successfully executed:

```
let success = false;
for (let x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  try {
    function1();
    success = true;
    break;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    continue;
  }
}
if (!success) {
  console.error('Function never succeeded!');
}
```

Comment: thank you so much ,let me try and get back